# Database structure/design: Courses according to semester and year

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am currently working with PHP and MySQL database.  I am currently building a course catalog page for my department. I have set up a table named `Courses` .  I am running into an issue with the rest of the structure for my database table. There are classes that are taught during the `fall` and others during the `spring`.  Also, among those classes, there are some that are taught every other year. I want to build a table which then I can use with PHP to automatically update according to the `semester` and `scholarly year`. More specifically, I would like to show the `courses name`, `description`, and if it’s either offered on the `fall or semester` of that year. Any course not offered that year will not show in the page.

How would I properly structure my table to fit the requirements mentioned above?

**Example (Course number, Class name):**

```
3210 Musical Theatre Styles I (Fall)
3220 Musical Theatre Styles II (Spring)
4500 Musical Theatre Showcase (Fall of year 2014)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create one table describing the courses, include course code, name and every other relevant information, then create another table linking those courses to when they will be taught.

Example of courses

```
id serial
course_code text
description text
```

Example of plan

```
id serial
course_id serial
year date
semester (look at @Mahmoud Gamals answer)
```

So a poulated database could contain the following:

Table `courses`

```
id course_code description
1  INF1000     "Basic programming"
2  INF1001     "More basic programming"
```

Table `course_dates` (0 for spring 1 for fall)

```
id course_id year semester
1  1         2012 0
2  1         2013 1
3  2         2013 1
```

This way, you separate the dates when the couses are taught from the info on the course.

Comment: +1 Thank you, One thing that i realized is also to define the `major` that the class belongs to: `INF1000` is part of the major `Computer Science` and `INF1001` may be part of the major `Information Systems`. How can I implement that to the table?

Comment: I like to organize such relations in meta tables. Since hypothetically a course can belong to several majors, putting the data from one into the other would force you to duplicate data. Thus, making a "`major-course-map`" linking the `id` of the major with the `id` of the course would easily let you get all courses related to a major.

Comment: I am little bit confused. I have tried pondering on this but I have not been able to grasp it. could you please write a query that will create this tables in my DB?

Comment: As I don't know the internal specifics of the tables you need, that would be hard. Also, I think it's a good idea that you, as the developer, knows how the db works. Read up on [ERD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) and use a simple drawing tool like [asciiflow](http://www.asciiflow.com/) to draw some simple diagrams. Understanding database design is important for every developer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a flag column. For example `int` to indicate the class type, 0 for `Fall`, 1 for `Spring` and 2 for `All of the year`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a few more details.  If you want it to be easy to remember use an ENUM ('fall', 'spring'...)

```
id courseID courseName whenOffered everyOtherYear
```